# vbs regex pattern to identify cvv entries in a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm looking for a RegEx.Pattern, which will help me identify entries within a string
which look like: CVV 123, cvv 123, cvv-123 or CVV-123 
or just a number 3 char long (i.e. "123"), so I can replace them with cvv-***. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
((cvv[-\s])?\d+)
```

This wil match all.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/24

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to match all the above mentioned formats,

```
(?:CVV|cvv)[ -]\d{3}
```